# Is there any possibility to make Rest API for C++ Builder6.0?

Tags: php, c++, api, c++builder, c++builder-6

Good day every one.

I'm working on PHP and I need to send information to another server, and company, which i need to send this information, faced with problem with writing Rest API on C++ Builder6.0.

I wonder if there is any possibility to make rest api, or is there any other ways for me to send information from my server on php to their server on C++ Builder6.0

Thank You in advance for help.

Comment: maybe you should add info/link about what Rest API is ... btw if it has api for MSVC++ like some DLL + header files then its most likely usable in BCB6 too ... you just need to create the lib files from dll in standard Intel format (as MSVC++ use its own non standard). You can use Borland tool and correct combination of switches like `implib.exe -c -f -a glut32.lib glut32.dll` ... the tool is in bin folder of BCB. For more info about this google OMF vs. COMF. Also its possible there is a VCL component for rest out there already

Comment: Thank You for advice Spektre, I will try this.

Comment: In order to use Dll you need to 1. Add to Project the lib file (or link it dynamicaly instead) 2. include the DLL header file (this might need some small tweaking if MSVC++ related stuff is messing with VCL or some config define required is missing or some include is missing. )  and that is all ... In case of custom VCL component is usually enough to just install/copy it to Borland and place it on form ...

Comment: REST is not a specific framework, but is more of an ideology. Any HTTP server can implement REST methods. There are several HTTP implementations that exist for C++Builder/Delphi that should be usable in 6.0.